# Diagonalizable unitary operators

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Let $u\colon H\to H$ be a unitary operator on a separable Hilbert space $H$ and let $(e_n)_n$ be a fixed orthonormal basis in $H$. Is it possible to decompose $u$ as $u=v^*dv$ where $v$ is a unitary and $d$ is a diagonal operator with respect to $(e_n)_n$?

Comment: are there non-diagonalizable unitaries?

Comment: I am not vey familiar with this topic. I thoght infinite dimensionality of $H$ might be a problem. If not, I would be grateful for a reference.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit basic for MO, but since the OP may not be familiar with operator theory: if an operator is diagonalizable it would have to possess lots of (non-zero) eigenvectors. Generally speaking operators on Hilbert space, even the unitary ones, need not have any (non-zero) eigenvectors. An instructive example is the operator $M: L^2({\bf T}) \to L^2({\bf T})$ given by $Mf(e^{it}) = e^{it}f(e^{it})$